# Numpy memory error while using audio analysis using python

Tags: python, numpy, pyaudioanalysis

I get the following error, while I test a more than 100 mb audio file.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\opensource\Desktop\pyAudioAnalysis-master\audioFeatureExtractio
n.py", line 542, in stFeatureExtraction signal = numpy.double(signal)MemoryError
```

Comment: `signal = numpy.double(signal)` tries to assign the whole signal to 1 `double` floating number.

Comment: `numpy.double` will broadcast over an `ndarray` @Maarten, so that's not the problem

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data was `int16` before, by upcasting to `float64`, you quadrupled the size of your array.  This is likely more than the memory you had left, and it threw a `MemoryError`